# Adding collate to mysql database

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I bumped into this error ,when execting sql

```
ERROR 1253 (42000) at line 25: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

So I try to add `utf8_general_ci` as the collate.

```
alter database mydatabase character set utf8mb4_general_ci collate utf8_general_ci;
```

I have error like this  How can I add the collate to existing database.

Or My idea is wrong?

```
ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
```

Thank you very much.

---

I try this

```
mysql> select * 
    -> from information_schema.collations 
    -> where CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8mb4' 
    ->   and COLLATION_NAME like '%general%';

+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
| COLLATION_NAME     | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN | PAD_ATTRIBUTE |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
| utf8mb4_general_ci | utf8mb4            | 45 |            | Yes         |       1 | PAD SPACE     |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

then I try this sql, it works

alter database mydatabase character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_general_ci;

but, first problem ( I am trying to introduce dump file)

```
ERROR 1253 (42000) at line 25: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' is not solved.
```

Comment: Use this to see which options you have: `select * from information_schema.collations where collation_name like 'utf8%general%';`

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE `DBname` COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you CHARACTER_SET_NAME is `utf8mb4` you have the option to choose from these *general* collations:

```
select * 
from information_schema.collations 
where CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8mb4' 
  and COLLATION_NAME like '%general%';
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CHARACTER SET` describes the *encoding* of characters.  It has a name like `utf8mb4`, `utf8`, `latin1`, `ascii`.

A `COLLATION` says how to compare or sort strings.  It has a name that *starts* with the `CHARACTER SET`, then has something else added on.  Most collations end in `_ci` (Case Insensitive) or `_bin` (Binary -- blindly compare the bits).

`utf8mb4_general_ci` is a very old collation; I recommend using a newer one, such as `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (available in most versions) or `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` (in MySQL 8.0).